# How can i store each address that interact with my smart contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, crowdsale

i am working on a crowdsale type of smart contract and i want to store everyone who sent ether to my contract .So i created a struture like this

```
  struct User { 
    address participantsAddress;
    uint id;
    uint participantETHamount;
  }
```

and my payable function like this :

```
  function invest() external payable {
 
    balanceOfContract=balanceOfContract+msg.value;
 
    mydata[id].participantETHamount = msg.value;
    mydata[id].participantsAddress = msg.sender;
    id++;

  }
```

but when I am debugging it, it seems like it doesn't store the values !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use at own risk. because i don't have enough information.

Idk if you want to add the data to an array instead of mapping. and not sure if id is only a counter or a real generated Id. Also not sure if people can invest more than 1 time

```
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

contract ContractC1 {

    uint256 counter;
    uint256 balanceOfContract = 0;
    mapping (uint256 => User) public users;

    struct User { 
        address participantsAddress;
        uint256 participantETHamount;
    }

    function invest() external payable {
        balanceOfContract = balanceOfContract + msg.value;
        User memory user = User(msg.sender, msg.value);
        users[counter] = user;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it worked